# install django-leaflet to match django version

Tags: django, python-3.x, leaflet, geodjango

I am playing around with geodjango and django > 1.11 is giving me ton of problems so I am using django 1.11

```
pip3 install django==1.11
```

now I am trying to install django-leaflet

which I installed

like

```
pip3 install django-leaflet
```

but this command upgraded to django 2 and broke my app.

so how do I install django-leaflet without upgrading my django

```
$ pip3 install django-leaflet==0.22.0
Collecting django-leaflet==0.22.0
Collecting Django (from django-leaflet==0.22.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/15/cfde97943f0db45e4f999c60b696fbb4df59e82bbccc686770f4e44c9094/Django-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from Django->django-leaflet==0.22.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4e/27c34b62430286c6d59177a0842ed90dc789ce5d1ed740887653b898779a/pytz-2018.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django, django-leaflet
Successfully installed Django-2.0.7 django-leaflet-0.24.0 pytz-2018.5
```

you see it installs django 2.0.7 which I DO NOT want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the dependency `django` only installed when it fail to detect any `django` installed in your system.

Anyway, if you can confirm your django already installed with `python3 -c 'import django'`, then you can force `pip3` not to install any new `django` by following command:

`pip3 install --no-deps django-leaflet==0.22.0`

But you have to install all dependency by yourself.

Comment: I will give this a shot. I have django 1.11 installed already so its still unclear why `pip3 install django-leaflet==0.22.0` would install it